Windows 10 - CORBA::ORB_init Error while trying to start IMC DHCP Manager
recently I've installed DHCPIMC_5.5.21.1 and I can't open it since I always get this error:
failed (Unkown exception trhown by CORBA::ORB_init )

I'm running Windows 10 updated as today, I have colleagues that installed it and can run it just fine. I've tried searching the error but nothing useful popped up so I wonder if someone could help me. Thanks.
